# I get an error when sending this sms

Tags: php

I'm using the clockwork api. The error code is: `Message failed - Error: Invalid 'To' Parameter`
I think it's beacause in the $message line. I've not set the variables correctly.

```
<?php
require 'class-Clockwork.php';

try
{
    // Create a Clockwork object using your API key
    $API_KEY = "API_KEY";

    $clockwork = new Clockwork( $API_KEY );

    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $message = $_POST['sendmessage'];
    // Setup and send a message
    $message = array( 'to' => '$phonenumber', 'message' => '$sendmessage' );
    $result = $clockwork->send( $message );

    // Check if the send was successful
    if($result['success']) {
        echo 'Message sent - ID: ' . $result['id'];
    } else {
        echo 'Message failed - Error: ' . $result['error_message'];
    }
}
catch (ClockworkException $e)
{
    echo 'Exception sending SMS: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: you probably meant `$sendmessage = $_POST['sendmessage']` , not `$message`

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = array( 'to' => '$phonenumber', 'message' => '$sendmessage' );
```

This should be

```
$message = array( 'to' => $phonenumber, 'message' => $sendmessage );
```

Otherwise you get the literal text `"$phonenumber"`, not the contents of the variable.